# using C struct with u8, u16 in Python dictionary

Tags: python, c, dictionary, struct, user-defined-data-types

So I have a C struct like this below

```
struct spi_header
{
    u8  SpiCmd  :5;
    u8  channel :1;
    u8  kac     :2;
};
```

which I need to use in python, so I tried using dictionary for this, as shown below

```
 spi_header = { 'SpiCmd': , 'channel': , 'kac': }
```

I tried assigning range for the members like `'SpiCmd' : (0:5)`
 trying to split the bytes into the range specified in the C structure. But I get syntax error. I know it is, because the range can't be specified (5, 1, 2) like how I tried. So how do I write in python, can any help me with this?

Comment: Is your question how to use bitfields in python?

Comment: First of all, note that this code isn't standard C to begin with. Using some 8 bit type for bit-fields is a non-standard extension. In addition, C does not specify the bit order either. So what this code does in C is anyone's guess.